# How to get latest props in componentWillUnmount?

Tags: reactjs, react-lifecycle

## I have a below parent component where I am updating id value to 2 which is a state of parent component and I am rendering the Child component only if id value equals to 1, if I do so Child component will definitely get unmounted.

## In Unmount method I need the updated props that is id equals to 2

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Child from './Child.jsx'
export function App(props) {
  const [id, setId] = useState(1);
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Hello React.</h1>
      {
        id === 1 && <Child id={id} />
      }
      <button onClick={() => setId(2)}>change value</button>
    </div>
  );
}

// Log to console
console.log('Hello console')
```

and a child component like below

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    }
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('componentDidMount', this.props.id);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('this.props', this.props.id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Child
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly problem do you want to solve?

Answer (score 0):

`id = 2` will never be passed to the child component, since as you said, when it's 2, the child will be unmounted. Hence, it can not be read from your Child's `componentWillUnmount`

If you're willing to change your architecture a bit, maybe don't unmount the child, edit your code to be something like:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Child from './Child.jsx'
export function App(props) {
  const [id, setId] = useState(1);
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Hello React.</h1>
      <Child id={id} />  {/* always render the child */}
      <button onClick={() => setId(2)}>change value</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('componentDidMount', this.props.id);
  
    if(this.props.id == 2) {
      // do something here
    }
  }

  render() {
    if(this.props.id == 2) return null; 

    return (
      <div>
        Child
      </div>
    )
  }
|
```

I am not sure if this will suit your use case.